# I would like to add a sonar to my simple project java

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I am working on a project using Ant, they need to add sonar to it. I wanna start with a simple example of project using sonar .which steps I must follow to add sonar to this simple project java

this is my simple class main

```
package com.sonar.test;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        exp01();
    }

    public void exp01() {

        System.out.println("Test test");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test();
    }

}
```

and this my build.xml file

```
<project name="Test" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class"  value="com.sonar.test.Test"/>



    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>


    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

Thanks for anybody who can help me.

Comment: I installed sonar and I configurated it with Mysql. I need just to add sonar to my simple project java

Comment: Go to the documentation home page: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation. Then type "ant" in the search box. Then read, and try something.

Answer (score 0):

In Build.xml add

```
<target name="sonar" depends="compile">
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
            <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
            <classpath path="path/to/sonar/ant/task/lib/sonar-ant-task-*.jar" />
        </taskdef>      
        <sonar:sonar />
    </target>
```

Full example available here - https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/java/ant/java-ant-simple/build.xml

Comment: I add this but it's not working with me. Anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: Can share what is the error message you are getting

Comment: Sure... the error is too long but it's like

C:\SAN_SDK_Test_Sonar\Test\build.xml:46: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server versio at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:49)
....
....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:9000/api/server/version' is invalid : 404